# Set server list as proxy and check for internet connection

Tags: networking, proxy

Hey I am in a network that has a certain amount of servers.

On port 80, one of them can be used as a proxy to connect to the internet, but I would like to find out if it is possible for the others that I found on Zenmap, too. However, there are too many servers to try out all them +doing that on different ports/settings.

Is there any script/program I could use for that? I have win7 64bit, Ubuntu 64bit, OSX, iOS and Android systems to let the program run on, available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is called *nmap*, it can do an amazing number of things, exists for Windows/Unix/Linux. The command you want to try is:

```
  nmap -p 80 192.168.0.0/24
```

(modify the network as per your needs). This command will test port *80* to see whether it is open. *nmap* can do an amazing number of things, have fun studying what you can discover with it.

Edit:

Actually, *nmap* can also scan not just port 80, but the function of proxying:

```
  nmap --script http-open-proxy.nse --script-args proxy.url=<url>
```

which can of course be easily scripted. You can find the reference [here](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-open-proxy.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but this will just check, if the server replies positively to that port-request. What I want to know is, if there is an actual open internet connection behind the servers.

Comment: @user2875404 What do you mean? If there is an actual proxy program running on the pc in question?

Comment: Each of these servers I found have 80 as a common open port. But having the port open does not automatically mean, I can get internet through them by setting this address as a proxy. That's why I need to check all of them (so far I figured out all that for one of them)

Comment: @user2875404 See my edit.